# How to check if one of the words in an NSString starts with a certain string?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, string-search

Given the string `This is just an example string to show what I mean.`

How do I check that none of the words in this string start with `amp`, or that one (or more) of the words start with `s`?

This is what the iOS contacts app does when searching in the list: It checks if the firstname or lastname start with the given search string.

The post that's supposed to be a duplicate, does not answer my question; it's just a general item about the use of regular expressions.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert Why duplicate? That post does not explain what I'm asking for.

Comment: Stupidly simple way:  Prepend both your large string and the search argument with a blank, then use `rangeOfString`.

Comment: Regular expressions _is_ an option. A combination of `componentsSeparatedByString:` and `hasPrefix:` is another.